# Cross Join 2 Select Statements (SQL)

Tags: sql

I'd like to cross join two select statements. Set up tables code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1] ([Letter] nvarchar(10), [Number] int)

INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES ('A', 1)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES ('A', 2)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES ('B', 1)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES ('B', 4)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES ('C', 10)

CREATE TABLE [Table2] ([Team] nvarchar(10), [League] nvarchar(10), [Player] nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO [Table2] VALUES ('Cubs', 'NL', 'Kevin')
INSERT INTO [Table2] VALUES ('Cubs', 'NL', 'Steve')
INSERT INTO [Table2] VALUES ('Yankees', 'AL', 'Steve')
INSERT INTO [Table2] VALUES ('Red Sox', 'AL', 'Carl')
INSERT INTO [Table2] VALUES ('Dodgers', 'NL', 'Tony')
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Letter] FROM [Table1]
CROSS JOIN
SELECT DISTINCT [Team], [League] FROM [Table2]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Name  |  Team  |  League

A | Cubs | NL
A | Yankees | AL
A | Red Sox | AL
A | Dodgers | NL
B | Cubs | NL
B | Yankees | AL
B | Red Sox | AL
B | Dodgers | NL
C | Cubs | NL
C | Yankees | AL
C | Red Sox | AL
C | Dodgers | NL
```

Thank you. (If the final result is the desired output but not sorted the same as mine, that is totally OK)

Comment: this is not mysl code, please tag the question correctly

Answer (score 5):

Your idea is fine, but `CROSS JOIN` is an operator only understood in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT l.Letter, tl.Team, tl.League
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Letter] FROM [Table1]) l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT [Team], [League] FROM [Table2]) tl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Revised code:

```
select * from
(SELECT DISTINCT [Letter] FROM [Table1]) a
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT [Team], [League] FROM [Table2]) b
```

Joins don't work like Unions, though I can see how you might be confused as to why!